# How to remotely deploy a client certificate to a fleet of Chromebook devices (ChromeOS)

Tags: google-chrome, google-workspace, google-chrome-os

I am trying to deploy a client certificate to my chromeOS devices (Chromebooks).

I have found a settings on this page (https://admin.google.com/u/2/ac/chrome/settings/user), but it only states "User management of installed client certificates." with the following options:

- Allow users to manage all certificates
- Allow users to manage user certificates
- Disallow users from managing certificates

I would like to be able to remotely manage those certificates.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Manage client certificates on Chrome devices](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6080885#zippy=) is the documentation you want. There are a lot of different ways to manage client certificates on a ChromeOS device and depending on what your needs are, you may require to develop an extension to manage them or work with your certificate vendor to help manage them.

Comment: I was looking for a menu inside Google Workspace to upload a client certificate and deploy it to multiple chromebooks. Sadly it does not exist. All the process needs to be done through a custom chrome extension. The documentation you provided is the one to follow. (fyi: we ended up dropping the client certificate and just using a token in the header provided by the extension)